# Safe to define overloaded functions with array inputs in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference, overloading

Is it safe to define the following two methods in C++ and use them without risk of them being mixed up in runtime?

```
void map(float (&a)[10], const double (&b)[6]);
void map(float (&a)[10], const double (&b)[3]);
```

or

```
void map(double (&a)[6], const float (&b)[10]);
void map(double (&a)[3], const float (&b)[10]);
```

They compile ok, so I figured their signature should be different and everything would be fine. However, I'm currently experiencing memory problems, so I want to make sure.

Comment: It is safe. Your memory problems must be elsewhere.

Comment: dude if you're having memory problems, you should see a doctor.  could be serious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe. Moreover, your sentence

> without risk of them being mixed up in runtime?

makes absolutely no sense because overload resolution takes place compile-time.